# duplicate menu on every page, want to delete

Tags: wordpress

I do not know how to get rid of this duplicate menu below (highlighted in yellow).

I am using wordpress.  When I open the page code editor it is not found or when I edit the page, but it is found on the preview page.  Spent 2 hours trying to find a way to get rid of this duplicate menu.

[highlighted in yellow is the duplicate menu that I cannot delete from wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwFGT.png)

Comment: I guess it is breadcrumb rather than menu.

Comment: i think this is breadcrumb i will give you better idea please share your link

Comment: Share link of code?  I have the pic showing what it is